# Cast "Map<String, List<dynamic>>" to "Map<String, List<String>>"

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to cast a `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Map<String, List<String>>`.

I have tried the following in Flutter:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMap = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'c': ['1', '2', '3'],
};
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap = dynamicMap;
```

But get the following error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<String>>'
```

I then tried:

```
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap = dynamicMap.cast<String, List<String>>();
```

which seems to work initally, but you get the same error when trying to use it, such as `print(typedMap)`.

Thanks for the help.

### EDIT

It's worth mentioning that the following:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMap = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'c': ['1', '2', '3'],
};
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap = dynamicMap.cast<String, List<String>>();
```

did in fact work (apologies for the mistake in the question).

However, when the data comes say from json like so:

```
String rawJson = """{
   "a": ["1", "2", "3"],
   "b": ["1", "2", "3"],
   "c": ["1", "2", "3"]
}""";
final Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMapFromJson = json.decode(rawJson);
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap = dynamicMapFromJson.cast<String, List<String>>();
```

The code no longer works and raised the exception mentioned.

The answers below helped solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMap = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'c': ['1', '2', '3'],
};
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap;
dynamicMap.forEach((key,value){
 List<String> list = List.castFrom(value);
 typedMap[key] = list
});
```

This is because a dynamic data type variable can be assigned with any of the data type at run time.
But values of typedMap here has been already declared with data type of `List<String>` , nothing else can be assigned to it other than a `List<String>`.
The error is because you're trying to asign a dynamic data type to a `List<string>`  data type, a pseudo example

```
String s = dynamic(); //impossible
dynamic s = String(); //possible
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: dynamic can be anything int,string,double,any random object, but typedaMap requires it to be List of strings not type dynamic, but what you are giving it is dynamic.

Comment: Edited the answer for future purposes

Answer (score 4):

Map method can help you to convert in your desire cast.

Check out follow code.

I also demonstrated how to access all value of map as a list. i hope this will work for you.

```
Map<String, dynamic> dynamicMap = {
    'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'b': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'c': ['1', '2', '3'],
};
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap =
    dynamicMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value));

typedMap.forEach((key, value) {
    print(value[0]);
});
```

Comment: Did you try will you given two variables? It is working fine. I tested before posting it.

Comment: I mean, your code doesn't show how to create the dynamic map.

Comment: As mentioned by the question, I have already tried that, but you get the following error:
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<String>>'` when in Flutter.

Comment: Can you add what changes you made in my code and it give you error

Comment: Looks like you made a small mistake on the code when declaring `typedMap`. Just edited it so works now.

Comment: Yes maybe because I edited from my cellphone. I hope now this work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I solution I ended up using and was most reliable was:

```
Map<String, List<String>> typedMap = dynamicMap.map(
  (key, value) => MapEntry(key, List.castFrom(value))
);
```

Thanks @Viren V Varasadiya and @iamyadunandan for the help