# Is it possible to get the index of DropDown items in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is the item list for the dropdown menu. Is it possible to retrieve the index when an item is changed/selected? This is the widget receiving the data from the future method with the API calls. Data is being received as a wholesome JSON file shown.

```
  Widget _buildList() {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return FutureBuilder<Parameters>(
      future: _futureParams,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Theme.Colors.color_7,
                            hintText: 'Select a Profession',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        value: _listdownValue,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        iconSize: 24,
                        elevation: 16,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _listdownValue = newValue;
                            // int j =
                            //     listAsMap.indexOf(listAsMap.where(listAsMap[i].service== newValue));
                            // price = listAsMap[j].price.match();
                            // print(price);
                          });
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null) {
                            return "Select a Profession";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        items: snapshot.data.services.map((item) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(item.service),
                            value: item.service.toString(),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.width * 0.05,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60, 0, 60, 0),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Theme.Colors.color_7,
                            hintText: 'Select an Area',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null) {
                            return "Select your Area";
                          }
                          print(i);
                          return null;
                        },
                        value: _dropdownValue,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        iconSize: 24,
                        elevation: 16,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _dropdownValue = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                        items: snapshot.data.locations.map((item) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(item.subCounty ?? ''),
                            value: item.subCounty.toString(),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.width * 0.05,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(0.0)),
                      color: Theme.Colors.color_8,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        width: 80,
                        child: Center(
                          child: const Text('Search',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Theme.Colors.color_7)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _futureSearch = createSearch(
                                this._dropdownValue.toString(),
                                this._listdownValue.toString(),
                                0);
                            saveSearch(searchP);
                            state = true;
                          }
                        });

                        print(this._listdownValue + "\ " + this._dropdownValue);
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.width * 0.05,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
        return Container(
          height: 150,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I want o get the price when the user selects a service. I can't directly set the value to price because I also need the string value of service.

```
{
        "services": [
            {
                "price": 3,
                "service": "Caregiver"
            },
            {
                "price": 5,
                "service": "Driver"
            },
            {
                "price": 0,
                "service": "Tipper Driver"
            }
        ],
        "locations": [
            {
                "sub_county": "All of NY"
            },
            {
                "sub_county": "Brkln"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: can you show us what are trying to achieve? value is the index! you can change it to int if you need to

Comment: Services is a list! Right? Snapshot.data is a map snapshot.data.services or snapshot.data['services'] is a List<Map<String,String>>

Comment: yes... it is a list. I am searching an Api with the service recorded and this is working correctly.  All i am attempting to do is upon hitting search, take the corresponding value of the price persist it to a preference and if a user checks_out that service, charge them the equivalent of price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  getDropDownMenuItems(snapshot) {
    Map<int, dynamic> mapWithIndex = snapshot.data.services.asMap;
    List<DropdownMenuItem> _items = [];
    mapWithIndex.forEach((index, item) {
      _items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem<int>(
          value: index,
          child: Text(item.service),
        ),
      );
    });
    return _items;
  }
```

call this method by passing the snapshot like this

```
items: getDropDownMenuItems(snapshot)
```

Comment: The solution is helpful but The implementation is a little confusing to me. would you please add a little execution

Comment: -this is causing a type error. type '() => Map<int, Service>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, String>'... changing it to either a class or dynamic doesn't solve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015263/12341099 this answer will be usefull for you

Comment: possible, these can be avoided if can use MobX, you will love it